# Declare [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)] at class level

Tags: c#, attributes, properties, xml-serialization

Is there a way to declare [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)] at class level so that all properties in the class will be XML serialized, even if they are null?

e.g.

`public BankAccount BankAccount { get; set; }`

Should result in `<BankAccount xsi:nil="true" />`, rather than the default missing element.

I tried this but the compiler (correctly) states that the attribute is not valid for class declarations.

The reason for this is that I don't want to have to specify this for all properties.

---

Edit: This is the serialization method I am using:

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(FormType);
        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        serializer.Serialize(stream, form);
```

Comment: Are you doing this with the `XmlSerializer` or the `DataContractSerializer`, and are you doing this in a web service? If you're using `XmlSerializer` outside of a web service you might be able to use an overload of `XmlAttributesOverride` to force the attributes (though I've never tried it). It may also be available in old ASMX style web services as well, but I'm fairly certain you can't do this with WCF with the `XmlSerializerFormatAttribute`.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` in a class to persist a class to an xml file.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at the `XmlAttributesOverride` class and using an overload of `XmlSerializer.Serialize` that accepts an instance of it. My understanding is that you can override all Xml attribute behavior explicitly be specifying overrides in an `XmlAttributeOverride` instance. I've never done it so I don't know how it works but I know I've seen similar questions with this as the answer.

Comment: It's going to deserialize as null anyway, regardless of whether it explicitly writes it as such, unless that's not the default in the parameterless constructor.  What exactly are you trying to achieve by this?  There's probably an adequate workaround.  (For example, if you just need to keep track of all public properties in some other application, you can easily do that with reflection.)

Comment: @Zenexer - This doesn't work with value types. [This](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/06/09/c-serializing-nullable-types/) blog provides an example using `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to be explicit when annotating your class for XML serialization.
Each property must be annotated with its own XmlElement attribute unless you want a default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

see this thread: [Setting the [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)] attribute at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686304/setting-the-xmlelementisnullable-true-attribute-at-run-time)

Comment: That link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, note this only covers simple nested classes

```
public class NestedClass
{
    public int MyNestedInt { get; set; }
    public int? MyNestedNullableInt { get; set; }
    public string MyNestedString { get; set; }
}

public class TestOverrideClass
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public int? MyNullableInt { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public NestedClass NestedClass { get; set; } = new NestedClass();

    public static string TestOverride()
    {
        string output = TestOverride<TestOverrideClass>(new TestOverrideClass());
        return output;
    }

    public static string TestOverride<T>(object objectToSerialize)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        // Create an XmlWriterSettings object with the correct options.
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = ("\t");
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

        // Create the XmlWriter object and write some content.
        XmlWriter writer = null;
        writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), GetNullOverrides<T>());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);

        return output.ToString();
    }

    private static XmlAttributeOverrides GetNullOverrides<T>()
    {
        // Create an XmlAttributes object with IsNullable set to true
        XmlAttributes attributes = new XmlAttributes();
        XmlElementAttribute attribute = new XmlElementAttribute { IsNullable = true };
        attributes.XmlElements.Add(attribute);

        // Create an XmlAttributeOverrides object
        XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

        AddOverRides(typeof(T), attributes, overrides);

        return overrides;
    }

    private static XmlAttributeOverrides AddOverRides(Type type, XmlAttributes attributes, XmlAttributeOverrides overrides)
    {
        // Apply the XmlAttributes to all properties T
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (!property.PropertyType.IsValueType)
                overrides.Add(type, property.Name, attributes);
            if (property.PropertyType.IsClass)
                AddOverRides(property.PropertyType, attributes, overrides);
        }
        return overrides;
    }
}
```