# Null properties in asmx return value

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asmx, nullable

I have an asmx service, and the methods return custom classes that have primitive data type properties.  When these properties are null, they are left out from the xml returned by the service.  I would like the service to still return the properties in the xml, but without a value.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How are you generating the xml?

Comment: Can you use [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable%28VS.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: The IsNullable element seems to do the trick.  Is there a way to specify it at the class level instead of on each property?

Comment: @user1365247: [I don't think so.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187047/declare-xmlelementisnullable-true-at-class-level)

Comment: You _might_ be able to do something with [XmlAttributeOverrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/athddy89%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and reflection, but likely it will cause nothing but pain long term. I suggest you adorn the relevant members with the attribute explicitly. It's the standard practice and gives you more control/flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adorn your properties with [`XmlElement(IsNullable = true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable%28VS.85%29.aspx). This will tell the serializer to include them even when null.